# Apply different materials to boolean cuts

Tags: materials, modifiers

I have this cube which is being affected by another mesh with a boolean and a solidify modifiers, making those inner cuts, is there a way to apply a different material for the inside and not the actual mesh without applying the boolean modifier? I'm trying to animate it and It'll make it a lot easier

Edit: I've added a material to the base mesh and it only applies the material to the outside which is a good thing, how do I go on from here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I've found a way to do it, you have to add two materials to the base mesh for it to work, once you've added them it's just playing with them to match the mesh with the materials